# how to implement redirection stdin in different functions in c++?

Tags: c++, redirect, iostream

In acm test I want to redirect the stdin in different funs  to file "in.txt" but It doesn't compile because of the conflict of std::istream cin and std::ifstream cin, how can implement it without cancel "using namespace out";

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;
ifstream cin("in.txt");
int a,b,c;
void read(){
cin>>a>>b;
}
int main(){
cin>>c;
cout<<a<<b<<c;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to change the function to take its input stream as a parameter. It's generally a good idea to rely on globals (such as `std::cin`) as little as possible:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int a, b, c;

void read(std::istream &in)
{
  in >> a >> b;
}


int main()
{
  std::cin >> c;
  std::ifstream f("in.txt");
  read(f);
  std::cout << a << b << c;
}
```

The comment about globals applies equally well to `a`, `b` and `c` of course, but I assume these were introduced as an example for posting.

Please also bear in mind that in actual code, you should *always* check that input succeeds, something like this:

```
bool read(std::istream &in, int &a, int &b)
{
  if (!(in >> a))
    return false;
  if (!(in >> b))
    return false;
  return true;
}
```

Comment: what i want to do is just redirect stdin to test file "in.txt",so i could test whether my program works well without changing my code,so i could submit my program to OJ with just comment out the redirection statment.

Comment: @laosheep What's wrong with doing that on the command line when starting the program? `myprog < infile.txt`?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>

std::ifstream cin("in.txt");
int a,b,c;
   void read(){
   std::cin>>a>>b;
}
int main(){
   cin>>c;
   read();
   std::cout<<a<<b<<c;
}
```

But this is not good practice...

Comment: Not that the OP's question is too clear, but I assume they want to use `::cin` in one of the functions. You're just using `std::cin` everywhere.